# Best Practice on reclaiming disk space in Cassandra 3.0 multi-node cluster

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

On my 5-node cluster, I issued various `drop table <keyspace_name>.<table_name>` commands. After that action, their data on individual nodes still persists under /var/lib/cassandra/data//

I would like to know if there has been any best practice on freeing up space.
Or, would the `rm -rf /var/lib/cassandra/data/<keyspace_name>/*` command on respective nodes suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, run this command to show hash of file directory contained data of keyspacse_1.table_1 in /var/lib/cassandra/data :

```
SELECT * from system_schema.tables WHERE keyspace_name='keyspace_1' AND table_name='table_1';
```

see the id of response query for this table.

and then check the files in /data that haven't this id and remove them.

for examlpe : id feteched in cql is : `d9b8ab90-1240-11e8-8680-f9685b9421a5` or other ids.

but  /data include dir similar below that this id not in response of cql! :

table_1-c9b8ab90-1240-11e8-8680-f9685b9321e5/

in this stage, you could  remove this file to freeing up space

Answer (score 5):

> would the `rm -rf /var/lib/cassandra/data/<keyspace_name>/*` command on respective nodes suffice?

Yes, that would do it.

Comment: I believe the directory that is being deleted should be at table level and not the keyspace level that is being mentioned in the question. Also “nodetool cleanup” wouldn’t work here, because the table has been dropped and hence snapshot at this point. Cleanup works with live table.

Answer (score 2):

When you drop a table, cassandra automatically creates a snapshot (just in case). If you're sure that you'll no longer need the data, you should run

```
nodetool clearsnapshot
```

on the affected nodes. Note that this form of the command will remove all snapshots. The complete command to specify a particular snapshot or keyspace in cassandra 3 is:

```
nodetool <options> clearsnapshot -t <snapshot> -- <keyspace> ...
```